# Mysqli - Should I reconnect everytime?

Tags: mysqli

I'm developing a project here and everytime I need to send a query to MYSQL I'm opening a new connection.

Is this right or should I only connect once? How should I proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should not open a new connection for every query.

There are exceptions to every general rule, of course, but typically you should connect once, sometime before the first query, and then re-use the same mysqli connection object for multiple queries during the given PHP request.

There is no limit to the number of queries you can run in serial using a given connection. The only limitation is that you can run only *one query at a time*.

Think of it this way: if you were writing a PHP script to simply read a file, and you knew you were going to read multiple lines from the file, you would keep the file handle open and make multiple read requests from it before you close the file. You would not re-open the file every time you wanted to read from it during a single PHP request.

The overhead of opening new connections to the database is reasonably low (at least for MySQL), but if you have an opportunity to easily reduce that overhead, it's likely worth it to  do so.

---

Re your comment:

You're right, there's no way to keep your $mysqli object across pages. That's what is meant by the term *request*.  Objects and resources are cleaned up at the end of a request.

When you said you were creating a new database connection for every query, I assume you meant that if you execute more than one SQL query during a single request (that is, page view), that you would create a new $mysqli object for each query. That would be unnecessary.

There's one other way you can reuse the database connections from one page view to the next. That is to use [persistent connections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php). This doesn't preserve the $mysqli object -- you still have to run `new mysqli` on each page load. But internally it is reusing the database connection from a previous PHP request.

All you have to do to open a persistent connection in this way is to add the prefix `p:` to your hostname.

Comment: Ok, but what should I do to keep my $mysqli object storing my DB connection between .php pages?

Answer (score 0):

Servers and databases have a finite number of connections available.  If every one of your users keeps an open connection for no reason (like when they are reading a blog post for a page that already loaded) then it will cap the number of people who can connect to your project in production.  Unless there is a very specific need to keep a connection open, I recommend not doing so.

Again though, it really depends on the scope of your project.  If you are just talking about a single page of a website, typically it's fine to leave the connection open until you are done loading the page.

Comment: Ok, so how could i avoid these multiple connections? How can I keep my mysqli connected between the page scripts?